# Why does the main function returns unexpected execution result?

Tags: java, inheritance, composition, software-design

I am trying to understand the source code:

```
public class InstrumentedSet extends HashSet {
    // Keeps the number of attempted element insertions

    private int addCount;

    public InstrumentedHashSet(Collection c) {
        super(c);
    }

    public boolean add(Object o) {
      addCount++;
      return super.add(o);
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection c) {
      addCount += c.size();
      return super.addAll(c);
    }

    public int getAddCount() {
      return addCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      InstrumentedHashSet s = new InstrumentedHashSet();
      String s1[] = new String[] {"Snap","Crackle","Pop"};
      s.addAll(Arrays.asList(s1));
      System.out.println(s.getAddCount());
      }
    }
}
```

I can not understand why does the main function return the **execution value of 6** instead of the **return value of 3**.

Comment: Why should it return 3?

Comment: Because we are iterating 3 Strings.

Comment: Where are you _iterating 3 Strings_ and what does that have to do with the count?

Comment: This is an example of Inheritance vs Composition. The solution of it starts on not override the method addAll, where the problem is delivery depends on details.

We will need to write addAll using iteration and add.

The problems are: 

- There is no code reuse;

- It may require access to private members;

In that way the better solution is Composition.

Comment: Add some `println` statements to your methods (or step through in the debugger), and all should become clear.

Comment: Can you please provide code which compiles? That would help to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Why do I still have negative votes on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, besides the fact that you current code doesn't compile it is possible to explain that behavior.

You're calling `addAll` on your new `InstrumentedHashSet` (or `InstrumentedSet`) instance and this method looks like this:

```
addCount += c.size();
return super.addAll(c);
```

First you're adding 3 to `addCount` and since that variable was 0 before, it will then be 3, as well.
Then you're calling `addAll` of the `super` class `HashSet` and [the implementation of it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) looks like this:

> ```
> public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
>     boolean modified = false;
>     for (E e : c)
>         if (add(e))
>             modified = true;
>     return modified;
> }
> ```

The most important part is the `if` statement: `if (add(e))`. It calls `add` for each item in the passed `Collection` and since you've [overriden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) that method with your own implementation:

```
public boolean add(Object o) {
    addCount++;
    return super.add(o);
}
```

... that method will be called instead of the parent implementation. And here you're increasing `addCount` for each added element. So you're now counting each element a *second* time.
And that is basically the reason why `System.out.println(s.getAddCount());` prints the doubled amount of the passed `Collection` from `Arrays.asList(s1)`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `HashSet`s implementation of `addAll` method calls `add` method and due to polymorhphism, `InstrumentedSet.add` is called.

Remove `addCount += c.size();` from `InstrumentedSet.addAll` implementation and it will work.